# delete columns in R for certain variables only

Tags: r

I have a dataframe x with column names that have a similar prefix (age_1, age_2, age_3,...,age_n). I want to delete columns with prefix 'age_' that are all NA. In the example below it will be age_2 and age_4. But in my dataset it might go up to age_100. Is there a way to do this?

Sample dataframe:

```
x <- data.frame("age_1" = c(0,1,1,0), "age_2" = NA , "age_3" = c(1,0,0,0), "age_4"=NA, "name_1" = NA, "name_2" = NA)
```

Sample output:

```
y <- data.frame("age_1" = c(0,1,1,0), "age_3" = c(1,0,0,0), "name_1" = NA, "name_2" = NA)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to select by two conditions: the column name starts with `age_` and all its elements are NA.  You can select those columns by:

```
sel = grepl("^age_",colnames(x), ignore.case = T) & sapply(x, FUN = function(x){all(is.na(x))})
```

and then do:

```
new_x = x[,!sel]
```

Result

```
  age_1 age_3 name_1 name_2
1     0     1     NA     NA
2     1     0     NA     NA
3     1     0     NA     NA
4     0     0     NA     NA
```

The `grepl(...)` will be true only for those columns that start with `age_`

The `sapply(...)` will go through each column and will return true when `all` elements are NA (`is.na()`).

The intersection of both is what you need to leave out (`sel` negated with `!`).

Comment: That did it! Worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
y_1 <- x %>% select(which(!(names(.) %in% grep("^[age]", names(.), value = T))))
y_2 <- x[colSums(!is.na(x)) > 0]
y <- bind_cols(y_1,y_2)
```

Not elegant but works

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use `colSums` and `grepl`

```
x[, as.vector(!is.na(colSums(x))) | grepl(pattern = "name", names(x))]
#  age_1 age_3 name_1 name_2
#1     0     1     NA     NA
#2     1     0     NA     NA
#3     1     0     NA     NA
#4     0     0     NA     NA
```

Comment: Yes, this one works nicely as well. But can you explain how pattern will work if there are more variable names with similar prefixes there, like gender_1, gender_2,..., gender_n?

Comment: @imprela the pattern would change to be `grepl(pattern = "name|gender", names(x))`, i.e. `name` or `gender`.